# Password Not Match - SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint site. This is a FBA site, and I have the Login.aspx page where I enter my user name/Password and I can login successfully. But, when I try to connect to the same service through Visual Studio/C#, it gives "Password Not Match" error.

```
using (net.Authentication authSvc = new net.Authentication())
        {
            authSvc.Url = @"https://**********/_vti_bin/authentication.asmx";

            System.Net.CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
            authSvc.CookieContainer = container;
            authSvc.AllowAutoRedirect = true;


            net.LoginResult result = authSvc.Login("username", "password");
            MessageBox.Show(result.ErrorCode.ToString());
```

When I use the same credentials on the `Login.aspx` it works. Any suggestions?